# How to override default shortcuts in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget which can contain one or more QTableView child widgets. By default, when I select a range in one of QTableViews and hit crtl+c only the leftmost uppermost cell gets copied to the clipboard. I would like to copy the entire range, so I implemented a copy() slot which does the job. I would like the copy slot to be accessible both from a context menu (when the user makes a selection and right clics the corresponding QTableView) and by the ctrl+c shortcut.

```
class Widget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void setupContextMenu();

private:

    QMenu* contextMenu_;
    QAction* copyAction_;
    QTableView* tableView_;

private slots:
    void copy();
}

void Widget::setupContextMenu()
{
    contextMenu_ = new QMenu(this);
    copyAction_ = contextMenu_->addAction("&Copy");
    copyAction_->setShortcut(QKeySequence::Copy);
    connect(copyAction_, SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this, SLOT(copy()));
}
```

When I select a range and right click, the appropriate context menu pops up and it even contains the name of the shortcut. When I click the "Copy" action in the context menu, the copy() slot gets executed. However the ctrl+c shortcut just copies only the leftmost uppermost cell in the selection as before. Also, the copy() slot does not get executed.

How can I repair this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe shortcut key doesn't work with contextual menus in Qt?

The handling of copy shortcut happens in `QAbstractItemView::keyPressEvent()`. You can [install an event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) to your QTableView watching for `KeyPress` event and handle your copy there.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying it now

Comment: Hmmm, but the thing that is bogging me is that the copyAction_ should have nothing to do with a context menu. Sure it belongs to one, but that should not impede it from being triggered by a key sequence.